# Pop a dictionary when one of the values are identical (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary value is different except for the value of 'name':

```
   list_dicts = [{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat']},
                 {'id': 678910, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['zebra']},
                 {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse']},
                 {'id': 141516, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['rabbit']}]
```

I would like to delete the second dictionary when the name is the same, but also add the additional pets values to the first dictionary.

**desired output:**

```
  output_list_dicts = [{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat', 'zebra']},
                       {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse', 'rabbit']}]
```

I am mainly struggling to identify the items with the same values. I assume after finding those, the items can be 'appended' to the 'pets' nested list and the other dictionaries eliminated using 'pop'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `name` is unique, you ideally want that as your dictionary key, so you can easily test if you've visited it before. Using `dict.values()` can then get the list output that you're after.

```
output = {}
for list_dict in list_dicts:
    if list_dict['name'] in output:
        output[list_dict['name']]['pets'].extend(list_dict['pets'])
    else:
        output[list_dict['name']] = list_dict

output_list_dicts = list(output.values())

print(output_list_dicts)
#[{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat', 'zebra']},
# {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse', 'rabbit']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.setdefault` for the task:

```
list_dicts = [
    {"id": 12345, "name": "Bobby Bobs", "pets": ["cat"]},
    {"id": 678910, "name": "Bobby Bobs", "pets": ["zebra"]},
    {"id": 111213, "name": "Lisa Bobs", "pets": ["horse"]},
    {"id": 141516, "name": "Lisa Bobs", "pets": ["rabbit"]},
]

output = {}
for d in list_dicts:
    output.setdefault(
        d["name"], {"id": d["id"], "name": d["name"], "pets": []}
    )["pets"].extend(d["pets"])

output = list(output.values())
print(output)
```

Prints:

```
[{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat', 'zebra']}, {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse', 'rabbit']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this.

```
import itertools

list_dicts = sorted(list_dicts, key=lambda x: x["name"])
output_list_dicts = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(list_dicts, key=lambda x: x["name"]):
    group = list(group)
    for g in group[1:]:
        group[0]["pets"].extend(g["pets"])
    output_list_dicts.append(group[0])

print(output_list_dicts)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat', 'zebra']}, {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse', 'rabbit']}]
```